# C++ program crashes sometimes when join()-ing threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency

Below is a sample but here's the whole code https://github.com/szlavalle/TFG

EDIT: I've narrowed down the cause to <s>the thread_local variables</s> the thread_index vector, which is thread_local. If I remove the thread_local qualifier on that vector, the program doesn't crash. Visual Leak Detector (can't use valgrind on Windows) doesn't report any memory leaks.

As the title stays, the program below crashes about 75% of the time. It's a whole lot of code, but you can ignore most of it I reckon. The problem is in the joining loop at the end of execute(). For some reason it crashes there about 75% of the times I run it on console. Never crashes on Visual Studio though. Is this some kind of Windows problem? Compiler flags or something?

Oddly enough, the program doesn't crash if I detach() instead of join() the threads, but that's not what I want. Seeing if a thread is joinable() doesnt fix it either.

```
using namespace std;

// These are all the thread_local variables

thread_local auto rng = default_random_engine{};
thread_local std::random_device rd;
thread_local std::mt19937 re(rd());    

thread_local int Duct::total_population = 0;
thread_local int Duct::dysfunctional_population = 0;
thread_local int Duct::total_reproductions = 0;
thread_local int Duct::dysfunctional_reproductions = 0;

thread_local int Duct::stem_counter = 0;
thread_local int Duct::bipotent_counter = 0;
thread_local int Duct::proglumepi_counter = 0;
thread_local int Duct::lumepi_counter = 0;
thread_local int Duct::mut_stem_counter = 0;
thread_local int Duct::mut_bipotent_counter = 0;
thread_local int Duct::mut_proglumepi_counter = 0;
thread_local int Duct::mut_lumepi_counter = 0;

thread_local int Duct::thread_index = 0;
thread_local vector<int> Duct::index_array;
thread_local Coordinate  Duct::boundaries = null_coordinate;

// Constructor
Duct::Duct(int l, int r, bool h, int n) :
    length(l),
    radius(r),
    HGP(h),
    diameter(r*2),
    n_threads(n),
    local_initialized(n,false)
{
    duct_type          = new uint8_t**[length];
    duct_housekeeping  = new uint8_t**[length];
    duct_protooncogene = new uint8_t**[length];
    duct_supressor     = new uint8_t**[length];
    duct_apoptosis     = new uint8_t**[length];

    for(int z=0 ; z<length ; z++)
    {
        duct_type[z]          = new uint8_t*[diameter];
        duct_housekeeping[z]  = new uint8_t*[diameter];
        duct_protooncogene[z] = new uint8_t*[diameter];
        duct_supressor[z]     = new uint8_t*[diameter];
        duct_apoptosis[z]     = new uint8_t*[diameter];

        for(int y=0 ; y<diameter ; y++)
        {
            duct_type[z][y]          = new uint8_t[diameter];
            duct_housekeeping[z][y]  = new uint8_t[diameter];
            duct_protooncogene[z][y] = new uint8_t[diameter];
            duct_supressor[z][y]     = new uint8_t[diameter];
            duct_apoptosis[z][y]     = new uint8_t[diameter];

            for(int x=0 ; x<diameter ; x++)
            {
                duct_type[z][y][x] = 0;
                duct_housekeeping[z][y][x] = 0;
                duct_protooncogene[z][y][x] = 0;
                duct_supressor[z][y][x] = 0;
                duct_apoptosis[z][y][x] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    //...

    if(n_threads > 1)
    {
        thread_barrier = new CyclicBarrier(n_threads + 1); 
        thread_locks   = vector<mutex>(n_threads-1);
    }
}

// The "Runnable"
void Duct::run(int begin, int end, int index)
{
    thread_index = index;
    boundaries = Coordinate(begin, end, 0);
    for(int z=begin ; z<=end ; z++)
    {
        index_array.push_back(z);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<total_generations; i++)
    {
        thread_barrier->await();
        next_generation();
        update_global_counters();
    }
}

void Duct::execute(int nGens)
{
    int step = length/n_threads;
    for(int i=0 ; i<n_threads ; i++)
    {
        int begin =     i*step;
        int end   = (i+1)*step-1;
        if ((i+1) == n_threads)
            end = length-1;
        // Passing pointer to ourselves to avoid having to make a whole bunch of variables static
        thread_array.push_back(thread(&Duct::run, this, begin, end, i));
    }
    for (int i=0; i<total_generations ; i++)
    {
        // ...
        thread_barrier->await();
    }    
    for(int t=0 ; t<n_threads ; t++)
    {
        // Program crashes here. Wrapping this in a if(joinable()) doesn't fix it
        thread_array[t].join();
    }
}

Duct::~Duct()
{
    delete thread_barrier;
    for(int z=0 ; z<length ; z++) {
        for(int y=0 ; y<diameter ; y++) {
            delete[] duct_type[z][y];
            delete[] duct_apoptosis[z][y];
            delete[] duct_supressor[z][y];
            delete[] duct_housekeeping[z][y];
            delete[] duct_protooncogene[z][y];
        }
        delete[] duct_type[z];
        delete[] duct_apoptosis[z];
        delete[] duct_supressor[z];
        delete[] duct_housekeeping[z];
        delete[] duct_protooncogene[z];
    }
    delete[] duct_type;
    delete[] duct_apoptosis;
    delete[] duct_supressor;
    delete[] duct_housekeeping;
    delete[] duct_protooncogene;
}

int main() 
{
    int longitud = 50;
    int radio    = 10;
    int n_gens   = 50;
    int n_hilos  = 4;

    chrono::time_point<chrono::steady_clock> tic, toc;

    tic = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    Duct duct1(longitud, radio, true, n_hilos);
    duct1.execute(n_gens);
    toc = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    double elapsed = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(toc-tic).count();
    cout << elapsed * 1e-9 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't get the program to compile; it complains about an undeclared identifier 'Duct'.  It will be a lot easier for people to help you find the problem, if the code included in your question can be compiled and run, so that they can play around with it instead of just stare at it and hope to see something.

Comment: Do not use raw pointers, use `std::vector` instead. Do not use `operator[]`, use `at()`.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner added a github link

Comment: @S.M. I used vector<thread> initially, but the problem's still there

Comment: Look at the world wider. `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>>>(length, std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>>(diameter, std::vector<uint8_t>(diameter)))` instead of `new uint8_t**[length]`, `new uint8_t*[diameter]`, `new uint8_t[diameter]`.

Comment: I suspect running this program under `valgrind` would likely catch some underlying memory-corruption errors.

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @S.M. fixed that, problem mentioned is still there