# C++ - thread_local vector causes crash on join()

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, mingw

EDIT: in the original question, thread_array was declared as `vector<thread> thread_array(4);` instead of `vector<thread> thread_array;`, which caused an error - this has been edited now, but the problem persists.

Coming from this question: [C++ program crashes sometimes when join()-ing threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49992361/c-program-crashes-sometimes-when-join-ing-threads)

I managed to narrow it down to this very simple program which hopefully you can compile and run easily:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

thread_local vector<int> v;

void foo(int n) 
{  
    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
        v.push_back(i);
}

int main() 
{
    vector<thread> thread_array;
    for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
        thread_array.push_back(thread(foo,100));
    for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
        thread_array.at(i).join();
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this program crash after reaching the second for loop (the joining one)? Is this a MinGW bug? As far as I know, I shouldn't be doing anything extra to the thread_local vector. I can post specifics if needed.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you've shown. Are you sure it's actually causing the problem you described? Perhaps you are using a slightly different piece of code.

Comment: This program runs without problem for me.

Comment: Are you still using "vector<thread> thread_array(4);" ?  cuz it looks like you edited that part. That can actually cause the crash.

Comment: @gchen That was the subject of an earlier answer to which OP commented that removing the `(4)` still caused the problem.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I don't always make the right decisions, but I would have left your answer and rollback intact.  If new code crashes, ask a new question.

Comment: @DrewDormann I hadn't thought of it that way. I'll proceed to do just that. Edit : Though on second thought, that would invalidate the comments to the question. I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: sorry folks, I didn't realize editing the question was improper SO etiquette (or just plain wrong on my part). I'll make a new question if need be.

Comment: @Kovalainen There is nothing wrong with editing a question. It's changing it's meaning that should be avoided as it removes context information for future readers who try to understand the comments and answers.

Comment: @Kovalainen you are also welcome to ask new questions when an answer evokes one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`thread_array` actually contains 8 objects. The 4 default constructed `std::thread` added by `vector<thread> thread_array(4);` and the 4 you `push_back` after. In your second loop, you try to `join` on the default constructed ones which aren't joinable.

To solve the problem, simply don't add 4 default constructed threads instead of using `push_back` :

```
int main() 
{
    vector<thread> thread_array; // <-- remove (4) from here
    for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
        thread_array.push_back(thread(foo,100));
    for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
        thread_array.at(i).join();
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can assign to the 4 default constructed ones :

```
int main()
{
    vector<thread> thread_array(4);
    for (auto & worker : thread_array)
        worker = thread(foo, 100);
    for (auto & worker : thread_array)
        worker.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are correct - I edited the sample code, and it still crashes when trying to join the threads, but not always.